# how to implement admob sdk in swift

Tags: amazon-ami

```
print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: " + GADRequest.sdkVersion())
bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"

bannerView.rootViewController = self
self.bannerView.delegate = self
bannerView.loadRequest(GADRequest())
```

i added `bannerView` in my app and add are comes good but automatically my admob account  has been block and no one add is comes and i create new account on admob with different email id and get unit id but on this unit id i cant;t get add .....what i have to do for real time add will comes trully..